# R: How to correctly prepare an international address for ggmap geocode / Google Geocode API?

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

I've found that

```
loc <- "Dradenaustraße 33, 21129 Hamburg"
library(ggmap)
geocode(loc, source = "google", force = TRUE, messaging = TRUE, output = "more")
```

returns either NAs, a "400, Bad Request" error, or if one tries to prepare the address as shown below, it even returns some Lat / Lon somewhere in Kansas.

I've found that,

```
loc <- "Dradenaustraße 33, 21129 Hamburg"
Encoding(loc) <- "UTF-8"
loc <- URLencode(loc, reserved = TRUE)
```

returns

```
Warning message:
In strsplit(URL, "") : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

and loc will be NA afterwards.

Btw. the following works fine with geocode, i.e. it returns the correct address and lat/lon:

```
loc <- "Dradenaustrasse 33, 21129 Hamburg" #manually reformatted
loc <- "Dradenaustraee 33, 21129 Hamburg" #misspelled
```

The following misspelled address has the same problems as the initial normal spelling:

```
loc <- "Dradenaustraée 33, 21129 Hamburg" #misspelled
```

I'm calling the geocode api with many thousands of addresses like the one above and don't want to reformat them (i.e. replace "ß" with "ss" unless this is absolutely necessary. In that case, I would have to make assumptions about many other international addresses containing accents (`, ´, etc.) as well.

Any ideas?

Many thanks! :)

Edited to point out that I'm looking for a solution that arbitrarily workds for international addresses and doesn't require domain specific knownledge and manual reformatting of addresses.

Comment: have you tried `draudenstrasse`? because `geocode` calls a `url` that needs to be valid.

Comment: I've edited my code to show that I've tried this, yes. My problem is more of a question of how to call the Googe Geocode Api or ggmap geocode with addresses containing non-ASCII characters. The API should be able to handle UTF-8 and as far as I know it's capable of that. So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong that results in such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding problem which are famously tricky. Your original text is not in utf-8 and that is what google is looking for. Setting the encoding is only attempting to attach metadata to the string. This:

```
Encoding(loc) <- "UTF-8"
```

Is telling R that the string is "UTF-8" and R is saying it is not. Your German words are probably in "[Latin9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)" encoding, which the R function `Encoding()` [has no idea what that is](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/Encoding).

What you can do is translate the encoding to UTF-8 before sending it to google. You can do this in-band before each call such as:

```
loc <- "Dradenaustraße 33, 21129 Hamburg"
utf_encoded <- //some translation algorithm
geocode(utf_encoded, source = "google", force = TRUE, messaging = TRUE, output = "more")
```

Or you can attempt to create a second data store (files, database tables, etc.) which is created by ingesting the German text through file or database reading, running it all through the algorithm, and outputting the equivalent text encoded as UTF-8 through file or database writing.

Either way, there's a string transformation / translation package [found here](http://www.rexamine.com/2014/05/icu-unicode-text-transforms-in-the-r-package-stringi/). The relevant part of that page looks to be:

> stri_trans_general("groß", "upper")
>
> `##` "GROSS"

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In a slight modification of your suggestion I used the following: `geocode(stri_trans_general(loc, 'latin-ascii'), source='google')`. This preserves the capitalisation. And the package that this function is from is `stringi`

Answer (score 0):

With a French laptop, I had to:

- use the French equivalent of Hamburg : *Hambourg*;
- replace the eszett (*ß*) by a *ss*;
- and separate the name of street from strasse: `loc <- "Dradenau strasse 33, 21129 Hambourg"`

After these changes, calling 
`geocode(loc, source = "google", force = TRUE, messaging = TRUE, output = "more")`
returned the desired results (lon = 9.89992, lat = 53.52478, etc.)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to worry about sending your input in a certain way to an API.

For me all variations of your input work on Geocode.xyz:

1. https://geocode.xyz/Dradenaustra%C3%9Fe%2033,%2021129%20Hamburg (with ß)

   - Germany x,y z: 53.52480,9.90007  |
   - 33 DRADENAUSTRASSE, Hamburg, Germany Confidence Score: 0.90
2. https://geocode.xyz/Dradenaustrasse%2033,%2021129%20Hamburg (without ß)

   - Germany x,y z: 53.52480,9.90007  |
   - 33 DRADENAUSTRASSE, Hamburg, Germany Confidence Score: 0.90
3. https://geocode.xyz/Dradenaustra%2033,%2021129%20Hamburg (misspelled)

   - Germany x,y z: 53.5248,9.90007  |
   - 33 DRADENAUSTRAßE, Hamburg, Germany Confidence Score: 0.5

The only thing the misspelling does, is change the confidence score.